# Group objects in an array according to two properties instead of one

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I have the following kind of array with objects I'd like to group (copied as JSON):

```
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "name": "jane",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "name": "peter",
    "lastName": "dickons",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "name": "eva",
    "lastName": "dickons",
    "gender": "female"
  },
]
```

If I want to group everyone by their last name, I can do so with this code:

```
const groupByObjectKey = (users: User[], key: string): any => {
    return users.reduce((rv: any, x: any) => {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);

        return rv;
    }, {});
};

const usersGroupedByLastName = groupByObjectKey(
    users,
    "lastName"
);
```

How can I now do the same thing, but use the same function and pass two keys to it and then group objects not only by lastName, but also by gender?

```js
const groupByObjectKey = (users, key) => {
  return users.reduce((rv, x) => {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);

    return rv;
  }, {});
};

let users = [{
    "name": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "name": "jane",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "name": "peter",
    "lastName": "dickons",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "name": "eva",
    "lastName": "dickons",
    "gender": "female"
  },
];

const usersGroupedByLastName = groupByObjectKey(
  users,
  "lastName"
);

console.log(usersGroupedByLastName);
```

Comment: how the output will look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the groupByObjectKey function to accept an array of keys instead of a single key. Here’s an example of how you can do this:

```
const groupByObjectKeys = (users: User[], keys: string[]): any => {
    return users.reduce((rv: any, x: any) => {
        const key = keys.map(k => x[k]).join('-');
        (rv[key] = rv[key] || []).push(x);

        return rv;
    }, {});
};

const usersGroupedByLastNameAndGender = groupByObjectKeys(
    users,
    ["lastName", "gender"]
);
```

This will group the users by both their last name and gender, creating a compound key by joining the values of the specified keys with a separator (in this case, a hyphen).